# Copy row from excel sheet into a new sheet withou copying doubles

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I'm relatively new to python. I have a sensor that counts dust. It writes its data into an excel sheet (DownloadedSheet). I want to create one large dataset where all data from the counter are (MainSheet).

When getting the data from the sensor it downloads the excel sheet with all last 10000 measurements, any older data gets overwritten.

I have the MainSheet into which all data is supposed to be copied, but I don't know how to look through the DownloadedSheet and compare this one to the MainSheet with all the data, and only copy the data that isn't in the MainSheet yet.

The one thing that all measurements have in common is the Date and Timestamps.
The Date is in one column and the Time is in another.

This is what an extract of the Dataset looks like:

```
Date    Time    Sample t    Vol.    Units   0.3um   0.5um   1.0um   2.0um   5.0um   10.0um
2019-10-06  09:44:38    00:00:21    0.99    L   0   0   0   0   0   0
2019-10-06  09:44:59    00:00:21    0.99    L   0   0   0   0   0   0
2019-10-06  09:45:20    00:00:21    0.99    L   0   0   0   0   0   0
2019-10-06  09:45:41    00:00:21    0.99    L   0   0   0   0   0   0
2019-10-06  09:46:02    00:00:21    0.99    L   0   0   0   0   0   0
2019-10-06  09:46:23    00:00:21    0.99    L   0   0   0   0   0   0
2019-10-06  09:46:44    00:00:21    0.99    L   0   0   0   0   0   0
2019-10-06  09:47:05    00:00:21    0.99    L   1   0   0   0   0   0
2019-10-06  09:47:26    00:00:21    0.99    L   0   0   0   0   0   0
2019-10-06  09:47:47    00:00:21    0.99    L   0   0   0   0   0   0
2019-10-06  09:48:08    00:00:21    0.99    L   0   0   0   0   0   0
2019-10-06  09:48:29    00:00:21    0.99    L   0   0   0   0   0   0
2019-10-06  09:48:50    00:00:21    0.99    L   0   0   0   0   0   0
2019-10-06  09:49:11    00:00:21    0.99    L   0   0   0   0   0   0
2019-10-06  09:49:32    00:00:21    0.99    L   0   0   0   0   0   0
2019-10-06  09:49:53    00:00:21    0.99    L   0   0   0   0   0   0
2019-10-06  09:50:14    00:00:21    0.99    L   0   0   0   0   0   0
2019-10-06  09:50:35    00:00:21    0.99    L   0   0   0   0   0   0
2019-10-06  09:50:56    00:00:21    0.99    L   0   0   0   0   0   0
2019-10-06  09:51:17    00:00:21    0.99    L   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Join the datasets together first and then drop the duplicate rows e.g.

```
import pandas as pd

main = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                     'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3']})

download = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5'],
                         'B': ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5']})

main = pd.concat([main,download])
main = main.drop_duplicates(keep='last')
```